# Find IDs of differing values grouped by foreign key in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table

`process` with the fileds `id`, `fk_object` and `status`.

example

```
id| fk_object | status
----------------------
1 | 3         | true
2 | 3         | true
3 | 9         | false
4 | 9         | true
5 | 9         | true
6 | 8         | false
7 | 8         | false
```

I want to find the `id`s of all rows where different `status`exists grouped by `fk_object`.

in this example it should return the `id`s  `3, 4, 5`, because for the `fk_object` `9` there existing `status` with `true` and `false` and the other only have one of it.

Comment: OK. So what have you tried so far?

Comment: IN ('true','false')... GROUP BY x HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT status) = 2;

Comment: @Strawberry: Thank you. This is working well enough. If you post an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stock response is as follows...

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... IN ('true','false')... GROUP BY ... HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT status) = 2;
```

where '2' is equal to the number of arguments in IN()

Answer (score 2):

This gets the `fk_object` values with that property:

```
select fk_object
from process
group by fk_object
having min(status) <> max(status);
```

You can get the corresponding rows by using a `join`:

```
select p.*
from process p join
     (select fk_object
      from process
      group by fk_object
      having min(status) <> max(status)
     ) pmax
     on p.fk_object = pmax.fk_object;
```

Comment: This will give him the entire rows, which should, in fact, have the id on them.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: Thank you for your help. But I get an syntax Error: unexpected where in both queries. MySQL 5.2.3

Comment: @Simulant . . . That should have been `having`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select id from process 
    where fk = ( select fk from process where status in ('true','false'));
```